Anyone know how to fix this?
I recently got an old Dell Optiplex 3040 Slim and tried installing Ubuntu using a USB. It was fully installed, and after it was done it asked for me to reboot the computer and the installation will be completed. However, after the reboot, this error message was the only thing that showed up:

RMRR
0.0756281 DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmuare reserved region can cover this [®×00000000₫₫800000-0×0000000fffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
0.099816] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/deu/sda3: recovering
journal
/dev/sda3: clean, 176110/61022208 files, 7251929/244058624 blocks

I’m still new to computer science so anything will help

You've provided few specifics.  I'm replying on a dell optiplex 3050 and had no issues installing, but I don't know what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, nor what installer/ISO you opted to download and use. You thus gave no clues as to what kernel stack you opted to use (LTS releases have choice; the default set by the install media downloaded/used but you gave us no details). Your pic shows only messages and not error(s), the fsck or file-system check probably the result of user-behavior (ie. unsafe shutdown such as power button used last attempt; rather than clean off).

Providing details of your hardware is helpful, ie. my own 3050 was sold with many choices of video card options, but you gave no specifics as to what was included on your machine..  For us to provide useful detail; we need to know what you're asking about, did you install Ubuntu Core?  Ubuntu Server?  Ubuntu Desktop?  or a Ubuntu flavor?  What release of that unstated product? and if you had choice of installer which did you use (eg. Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop has two ISOs using different installers available).. 22.04 being a LTS has kernel stack options selected via ISO used..

I am no expert either but based on what you wrote it seems like the old computer you have does not have a motherboard that can run the version of Ubuntu you downloaded.
Here are two suggestions you could try:
Consider downloading an older version of Ubuntu, for example 20.04 or even 18.04 (maybe even older depending on how old the dell is). If you do some Googling you should be able to find places to download them.
A more complicated approach would be to try and update the BIOS. This is a lot more involved. You would need to dig around Dell's website for the drivers, you would probably need a working Windows OS to run the BIOS update, and if you make a mistake at any point, you could "brick" the system making it completely unusable. And even if you do everything right, there is still a very good chance that the laptop is simply too old to run the latest Ubuntu edition.

I’ll try installing an older version, but this computer is very old (so old my school gave it to me for free) so there might not be many options to save it. Thank you for the tip tho, I’ll give it a try.

Thanks for the help but I just realized I’m kinda dumb, I just hard reset the computer and now it’s working just fine. Idk what the error message was but it seems to be fine now.

I would not suggest people install an EOSS release such as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS unless there are warnings included... ie. 18.04 being EOSS does not get security updates & shouldn't be used online unless ESM or Pro is enabled....  I use a 2005 HP Compaq to run the latest release in QA which is much older than a machine introduced in 2017.. that should run all without issue.. No details of GPU were provided which I consider key, as well as no clues as to what Ubuntu product/release etc..

Glad to hear you for it working!
